# Every time GIT push source code to Magento Cloud, it will show 'Service Temporarily Unavailable'

Tags: magento2, http-error-500, maintenance, hard-delete

Every time GIT push source code to Magento Cloud, it will show 'Service Temporarily Unavailable'
I have googled found some solution that deletes the .maintenance.flag file in /var. 
But this action I need to do it after every GIT push action. is it has another method to solve this problem?

Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Comment: It might be file permission issue

Comment: what does it mean? Since Magento Cloud that's a cloud hosting service, I couldn't set any permission. and disable maintenance mode.

Comment: Sorry, donot have enough idea on Magento cloud,May be other people help